# What is the index path of a table view cell that is currently being rearranged (moved) by the user?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

When a table view is in editing mode and the user is moving cells around.  What is the index path of the cell currently being moved?  How are the index paths of the remaining cells affected?

(I'm actually trying to learn this in order to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717566/custom-grouped-table-view-cell-updates-background-image-in-relation-to-position).)

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView          targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section)
{
    return sourceIndexPath;
}

return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Do not forget to do another check in your tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: data source method as shown below, you do not want to run your application logic when the destination is similar to the source.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
if(sourceIndexPath == destinationIndexPath)
    {
    return;        
    }

//application logic
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm still unable to update the background image for the cell, *while* the user is moving it, when using this.  I'm trying to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717566/custom-grouped-table-view-cell-updates-background-image-in-relation-to-position

Comment: Use the delegate! Copy from the Delegate:// Called before the user changes the selection. Return a new indexPath, or nil, to change the proposed selection.
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: You are right about getting the index path.  I'm still having trouble redrawing the cell background, but I guess that is a separate question.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes is a separate question with the same answer: Delegate! Do you know that when you click with ALT on your delegate (in your header file) you can see its functions/protocols? You will find there:didSelectRowAtIndexPath I suppose you can change your background there!

Comment: I've tried using many delegate methods.  Like I mentioned in the other question, I can achieve the effect *after* the cell has been moved, but not *while* it is being moved by the user.  `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does not work either.  I tried it before, but tried it again just now to make sure.

Comment: I'm trying to get the effect as seen when rearranging apps in Settings > Notifications > In Notification Center.  The cell backgrounds should update depending on whether they are at the top, middle, or bottom of a section (or if the cell is the only row in the section).

Answer (score 0):

Let the delegate take care of this problem for you. Thats why its there!
– tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:

Comment: I tried messing around with this delegate method, but couldn't use it to update the cell backgrounds for grouped table views.  Can you show how I would configure the cell being moved with `-tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`?